# ClassNotFount Exception: com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsManager

Tags: web8, experience-optimization

I'm implementing SDL Web Experience Optimization 8 with Experiments. The Experiments are showing in a Page without any issues. But when I try to enable Google Analytics for Experiments I'm getting below error:

> ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsManager

I have followed SDL document to setup the Experiments and Analytics as well. Am I missing any jar files?

I cannot find the above class in `smarttarget_core.jar`. Other jar files I'm using related to Experience Optimization are `smart target_cartridge.jar`, `session_cartridge.jar`, `smarttartget_entitymodel.jar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the installation media of your Experience Optimization release, you will find the following folder:

`Content Delivery\roles\api\google-analytics-provider\lib`

In there are 10 more jars, the last one named `smarttarget_google-analytics.jar`, which is the one that contains your missing class.

Following the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-508A9E3F-62E0-46C9-9399-A3B211AE836A), you should:

> From the installation media folder `Content Delivery\roles\api\google-analytics-provider\lib\`, copy all files to the `WEB-INF/lib/` subfolder of the Web application.

So it looks like you missed a step.

Comment: After adding those jars now the issue is resolved. But, still I need to complete the configurations at GA end to complete the analytics part. @Bart Thanks for your answer.